# Localization system filesystem in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, localization, internationalization, netbeans-platform

I am trying to do localization for Netbeans RCP, and I am stuck when I tried to make layer.xml reads properties from Bundle.properties. It reads it and change names in netbeans project tree, but what I want to achieve is to change name in application.

```
<folder name="Folder 1">
    <attr intvalue="2" name="position"/>
    <folder name="subfolder 1" >
         <attr intvalue="0" name="position"/>
    </folder>
    <folder name="subfolder 2" >
         <attr intvalue="0" name="position"/>
    </folder>
</folder>

<folder name="Folder 2">
    <attr intvalue="2" name="position"/>
    <folder name="subfolder 1" >
         <attr intvalue="0" name="position"/>
    </folder>
    <folder name="subfolder 2" >
         <attr intvalue="0" name="position"/>
    </folder>
</folder>
```

A lot of classes uses path of folders and this is hardcoded i .e

```
@ActionReference(path = "folder 1/sufolder 2", position = 1)
```

When I am launching app with different locale than default (for example Spanish) it loads Bundle_es_ES.properties file that contains spanish translation. I also want to translate names of folders because those are displayed in the app. Only clues I have found was to add attributed "displayName" that reads parameter from Bundle.properites file. It does not work in way I wanted.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Damian I have the exact same issue . I know this post is quite old, but did you get an answer?

Answer (score 0):

In your layer.xml you need to add the `displayName` attribute to your localizable folders, like this:

```
   <folder name="subfolder1" >
         <attr intvalue="0" name="position"/>
         <attr name="displayName" bundlevalue="org.path.to.Bundle#Actions/subfolder1">
   </folder>
```

then Netbeans will use the entry "Actions/subfolder1=xxx" from the localized Bundle_xx_XX.properties.

The Netbeans IDE can make these changes for you: edit layer.xml from the IDE, select subfolder1, right-click menu "Localize Name".